# How to get all text after specific char?

Tags: c

I wrote a little program which prints help information if argument is not passed.

If I run the app without arguments

```
./myApp
```

it prints

```
./myApp --filename=file
```

I know that argv[1] holds the first parameter, but I can't figure out how to fetch the text after "=" ie the name of file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of parsing the string manually, you should rather use [`getopt()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getopt) or [`getopt_long()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getopt_long).

They do the dirty work for you and behave in the way people expect it (while self-written parsers are sometimes confusing - some use `--arg value`, others `--arg=value`, some even use `-arg value`)

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to parse it yourself. `strtok` is very useful for that, another one is `strstr`. There are also some ready libraries which allow you importing this functionality into your project, if you don't want to write it all yourself, like [this one](http://argtable.sourceforge.net/) for example.

Answer (score 0):

[`strchr()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strchr.html) returns a pointer to the character. The next characters are what you want

```
char *equals;
equals = strchr(argv[1], '=');
if (equals) {
    printf("Rest of argument: %s\n", equals + 1);
} else {
    printf("No equal found in argv[1] (%s)\n", argv[1]);
}
```

Depending on your specific needs, you may want to copy them somewhere or just use them right from the argv[1] argument.

Comment: I tried the code you suggest but I get this warning - 
passing argument 2 of ‘strchr’ makes integer from pointer without a cast

Comment: Did you perhaps write double quotes to delimit the `=`? They're single quotes!

Answer (score 0):

Use strchr-function to find the '=' character. Check the strchr return value. If return value is non-NULL, increment it by one and you have what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of parsing the stuff yourself you could use argp the libc argument-parser:

http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/libc/Argp.html

Answer (score 0):

The strings in Argv is separated by whitespaces, so you would have to parse the argv[1] string to fetch the text after '='. However there is some functions called `getopt()` and `getopt_long()`, that are part of the POSIX standard.

If this functions are available to you, you can use `getopt_long()` to get both the short, and the long options (e.g. filename), and its argument (e.g. file).

Link includes explanations and examples: 
http://www.chemie.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/libc/libc_22.html